# Consultas ao Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Estou com um erro quando realizo as consultas no firebase, meu código para consulta esta da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

    txtNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNomePerfil);
    txtCpf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCpfPerfil);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailPerfil);
    txtFone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCelularPerfil);
    txtPlaca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPlacaPerfil);
    imgPerfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPerfil);
    txtNomeFantasia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNomeFantasiaPerfil);
    txtCnpj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCnpjPerfil);

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    uId = firebaseUser.getUid();
    email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.child("Usuario").child(uId).child("nome")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          nome = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            txtNome.setText(nome);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


   DatabaseReference mReferenceCpf = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("Usuario").child(uId).child("cnpjCpf")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         cpf = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            txtCpf.setText(cpf);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    DatabaseReference mReferencePlaca = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mReferencePlaca.child("Funcionario").child(cpf).child("placa")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    placa = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    txtPlaca.setText(placa);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Entretanto estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> **Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ucarparceiro.ucarapp.com.ucarparceiro/ucarparceiro.ucarapp.com.ucarparceiro.Activity.ActivityPrincipal.ActivityPerfil}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()**
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2316)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2376)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:147)
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1281)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5253)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:694)

Os dados no Firebase estão da seguinte forma.
[image: Nó Usuário]
[image: Nó Funcionario]

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Uma das variáveis, ou uId ou cpf está null, por isso.

Answer (score 1):

Você está tendo esse erro porque o método `onDataChange()` é assíncrono, isso significa que quando você chama o `child(cpf)`, o `cpf` ainda é `null`.

Você teria de ler a placa dentro do `onDataChange()` do cpf:

```
DatabaseReference mReferenceCpf = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("Usuario").child(uId).child("cnpjCpf")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            cpf = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            txtCpf.setText(cpf);
            DatabaseReference mReferencePlaca = 
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mReferencePlaca.child("Funcionario").child(cpf).child("placa")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        placa = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        txtPlaca.setText(placa);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```